# How do you change the Back and Foreground Color of a CIFilter CIQRCodeGenerator Filter

Tags: macos, cocoa, qr-code, cifilter

I'm trying to make a QR Code Generator for OS X but i haven't had succession in making a QRCode that can be more colourful that the black and white ones I'm using the CIQRCodeGenerator for the CIImage Filters how would i make this work I've got a sample code that I've implemented into my app :-

```
+ (NSImage *)createQRImageForString:(NSString *)string size:(CGSize)size {
// Setup the QR filter with our string
CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIQRCodeGenerator"];
[filter setDefaults];

NSData *data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[filter setValue:data forKey:@"inputMessage"];
CIImage *image = [filter valueForKey:@"outputImage"];

// Calculate the size of the generated image and the scale for the desired image size
CGRect extent = CGRectIntegral(image.extent);
CGFloat scale = MIN(size.width / CGRectGetWidth(extent), size.height / CGRectGetHeight(extent));

// Since CoreImage nicely interpolates, we need to create a bitmap image that we'll draw into
// a bitmap context at the desired size;
size_t width = CGRectGetWidth(extent) * scale;
size_t height = CGRectGetHeight(extent) * scale;
CGColorSpaceRef cs = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGContextRef bitmapRef = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, width, height, 8, 256*4, cs, (CGBitmapInfo)kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);

#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
#else
CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithCGContext:bitmapRef options:nil];
#endif

CGImageRef bitmapImage = [context createCGImage:image fromRect:extent];

CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(bitmapRef, kCGInterpolationNone);
CGContextScaleCTM(bitmapRef, scale, scale);
CGContextDrawImage(bitmapRef, extent, bitmapImage);

// Create an image with the contents of our bitmap
CGImageRef scaledImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmapRef);

// Cleanup
CGContextRelease(bitmapRef);
CGImageRelease(bitmapImage);

return [[NSImage alloc] initWithCGImage:scaledImage size:NSZeroSize];
}
```

So can someone Point me in the right direction please.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here's an example in swift (for the googlers)

```
func qrCode(from string: String) -> UIImage? {
    let data = string.data(using: .ascii)

    // Generate the code image with CIFilter
    guard let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIQRCodeGenerator") else { return nil }
    filter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")

    // Scale it up (because it is generated as a tiny image)
    let scale = UIScreen.main.scale
    let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale)
    guard let output = filter.outputImage?.transformed(by: transform) else { return nil }

    // Change the color using CIFilter
    let colorParameters = [
        "inputColor0": CIColor(color: UIColor.black), // Foreground
        "inputColor1": CIColor(color: UIColor.clear) // Background
    ]
    let colored = output.applyingFilter("CIFalseColor", parameters: colorParameters)

    return UIImage(ciImage: colored)
}
```

Comment: From the docs:
Generates an output image representing the input data according to the ISO/IEC 18004:2006 standard. The width and height of each module (square dot) of the code in the output image is one point. **To create a QR code from a string or URL, convert it to an NSData object using the NSISOLatin1StringEncoding string encoding**.

Answer (score 12):

Heres the Code that works Now :-

```
+ (NSImage *)createQRImageForString:(NSString *)string backgroundColor:(CIColor*)iBackgroundColor foregroundColor:(CIColor*)iForegroundColor size:(CGSize)size {

CIImage *image;
CIFilter *filter;
CIFilter *filterColor;

// Setup the QR filter with our string
filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIQRCodeGenerator"];
[filter setDefaults];

NSData *data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[filter setValue:data forKey:@"inputMessage"];
image = [filter valueForKey:@"outputImage"];

filterColor = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIFalseColor" keysAndValues:@"inputImage", image, @"inputColor0", iForegroundColor, @"inputColor1", iBackgroundColor, nil];
//[filterColor setDefaults];

image = [filterColor valueForKey:@"outputImage"];


//image = [CIImage imageWithColor:[CIColor colorWithRed:1 green: 0 blue: 0]];

// Calculate the size of the generated image and the scale for the desired image size
CGRect extent = CGRectIntegral(image.extent);
CGFloat scale = MIN(size.width / CGRectGetWidth(extent), size.height / CGRectGetHeight(extent));

// Since CoreImage nicely interpolates, we need to create a bitmap image that we'll draw into
// a bitmap context at the desired size;
size_t width = CGRectGetWidth(extent) * scale;
size_t height = CGRectGetHeight(extent) * scale;
CGColorSpaceRef cs = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGContextRef bitmapRef = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, width, height, 8, 256*4, cs, (CGBitmapInfo)kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);

#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
#else
CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithCGContext:bitmapRef options:nil];
#endif

CGImageRef bitmapImage = [context createCGImage:image fromRect:extent];

CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(bitmapRef, kCGInterpolationNone);
CGContextScaleCTM(bitmapRef, scale, scale);
CGContextDrawImage(bitmapRef, extent, bitmapImage);

// Create an image with the contents of our bitmap
CGImageRef scaledImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmapRef);

// Cleanup
CGContextRelease(bitmapRef);
CGImageRelease(bitmapImage);

return [[NSImage alloc] initWithCGImage:scaledImage size:NSZeroSize];
}
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks for posting this. I hope you don't mind if I use this method in my Mac app. Oh, perhaps it's my naivety, but shouldn't scaledImage be released before you return the final NSImage?

Comment: Your Welcome These Basic things need to be Exposed to the Internet in order for more people to learn about these complex Methods like filters Like QR Codes. The Method still works without scaledImage being released its stable enough for Me.

Comment: From the docs:
**To create a QR code from a string or URL, convert it to an Data object using the `.isoLatin1` string encoding**. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIQRCodeGenerator

Comment: can you please update your answer? return [[NSImage alloc] initWithCGImage:scaledImage size:NSZeroSize]; is giving me the error.

Answer (score 9):

`CIQRCodeGenerator` only generates QR codes in black and white, but you can easily transform the resulting image to another color scheme.

Create an instance of the  [`CIFalseColor`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIFalseColor) filter, set its `inputImage` to  the `outputImage` from your generator, and its `inputColor0` and `inputColor1` to the colors you want to use instead of black and white. Then draw the false color filter's `outputImage` into your CG context.

You could also consider using the [`CIMaskToAlpha`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIMaskToAlpha) filter to turn either the black or white in the QR code image to transparent; then you'll be able to put it on top of any background color. (Just don't put it on too busy a background or people won't be able to scan it.)

Comment: Im Guessing inputColor0 is the background Color and inputColor1 is the Foreground Color

Comment: It's actually the other way around :)

Comment: Great! It is possible to add gradients foreground instead of default black color?